# importing iPhoto library to Lightroom (preserving rating and events if possible)

Tags: photos, import, iphoto, pictures, adobe-lightroom

I'm trying to switch to Lightroom, currently using iPhoto, so I'd like to import all my existing libraries while keeping photo ratings, events and tags too.

Is there a way to do that? Ratings are the most important think I'd like to be able to import.

I'm currently using iPhoto 9 and Lightroom 2 - but I guess I could update (iPhoto) if that would help

Comment: FYI I guess there's no Lightroom CS4, there is only Lightroom 1 to 3. Interesting question though.